# Dataframe with scipy minimize function

Tags: python, scipy, minimize, mse

Im trying to minimize sum square function that works with a dataframe. The df is as follows:

```
ds = pd.DataFrame({'t': [*np.linspace(0,300,7)], 'Ca': [0.05, 0.038, 0.0306, 0.0256, 0.0222, 0.0195, 0.0174]})
```

My model that Im using with sum square is:

```
def model(params, t, ca0=0.05):
    alpha = params[0]
    k = params[1]
    ca_pred = (ca0**(1-alpha) - (1-alpha)*k*t)**(1/(1-alpha))
    return ca_pred

def sum_of_squares(params, t, ca, ca0=0.05):
    ca_pred = model(params, t, ca0)
    obj = ((ca - ca_pred)**2).sum()
    return obj

Initial guess:
params = [1.5, 0.05]
```

My specific doubt is here, I dont know how to pass dataframe to use "t" and "ca" in sum_of_squares function in minimize:

```
res = minimize(fun=sum_of_squares, x0=params, tol=1e-3, method="Powell")
```

Comment: If a list serves, you may use model(params, ds).values.     t = [x[0] for x in model(params, ds).values]    ca = [x[1] for x in model(params, ds).values]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use the `args` argument:

```py
minimize(sum_of_squares, x0=params, args=(ds['t'], ds['Ca']), tol=1e-3, method="Powell")
```

or wrap the function:

```py
minimize(lambda x: sum_of_squares(x, ds["t"], ds["Ca"]), x0=params, tol=1e-3, method="Powell")
```

Comment: Ooh ok ok, got it. I saw it in the documentation, but I didn't know if it was the right way to use it. Thanks!